# How can I rob the church collection box if I'm not playing a rogue?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I've just picked up the [Tithe Box from Dawnbringer Natrisse](http://www.gamebanshee.com/neverwinternights2/walkthrough/neverwinterblacklakedistrict.php), who has asked me to deliver it to Brother Merring back in West Harbor. I remember from past playthroughs that it's possible, through some skill checks, to open the box, and skim a little off the top before making the delivery for some bonus XP, Gems, and Gold. Unfortunately, while I seem to be able to buff myself enough to pass the initial Search check, I can't pass the Disable Device check, nor can I pawn it off to Neeshka.

What's the minimum Disable Device skill required to rob the church box? Are there other, further skill checks required that I'm forgetting about? Or is it just flat out impossible to get enough Disable Device from buffs and equipment alone to pass this check as anything other than a Rogue?

Answer (score 11):

**Minimum Disable Device skill rank required: 16**

It uses the raw skill rank only, and does not take into account any skill buffs or ability bonuses.

To figure this out, I opened up the NWN 2 campaign in the toolset editor, and tracked down the conversation script for the tithe box.

### Conversation Script

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3AlO.png]
Click the image to open in the entire window.  You may have to click on the image again to zoom in.

### Key Points from the Script

- `gc_skill_rank(19,15)` Player can detect the trap if they have a Search skill of 15.
- `gc_skill_rank(7,16)` Player can disarm the trap if they have a Disable Device skill of 16.

#### gc_skill_rank function

```
gc_skill_rank(int nSkill, int nRank)
Determine if PC Speaker has sufficient rank in a particular skill.

Parameters:
int nSkill = skill int to check (19 == Search, 7 == Disable Device)
int nRank = minimum rank to return TRUE
```

`gc_skill_rank` checks for raw skill ranks only; It does not consider skill buffs or ability bonuses.

Assuming the Player has both a Search skill rank of 15, and a Disable Device skill rank of 16, they will be able to find the trap and disarm it.  There are no other conditions in the script that would prevent robbing from the church box.

### Achieving the Required Skill Level

#### [Skill Caps](http://nwn2.wikia.com/wiki/Character_progression)

```
Class Skills: (Character Level + 3)
Cross-Class Skills: (Character Level + 3) / 2 [rounded down]
```

Four classes have [Disable Device as a Class Skill](http://nwn2.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_Device): **Rogue, Arcane Trickster, Assassin, Shadow Thief**.  Your skill cap will stay at Class Skill level as long as you have at least 1 level of one of these classes, even if your current class is different.

So, in order to get your Disable Device [skill rank](http://nwn2.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_rank) up to 16, you need one to do one of the following:

- Be at least character level 13, and one of your classes has to be a Rogue, Arcane Trickster, Assassin, or Shadow Thief of Amn.
- Be at least character level 29.

Comment: That minimum level disregards the significant +Skill buffs available, as well as the bonus to the skill from Intellect, but otherwise, this is super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I mentioned this, but its kind of easy to miss.  I'll update the answer to make it more prominent.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that raw skill rank claim -  I've successfully detected the trap with equipment before, but not been able to disarm it.

Comment: Its surprisingly hard to find good documentation for the nwn scripting language after all these years.  In addition, they seem to have made some changes to key functions from nwn1 to nwn2 which aren't well documented.  I traced back the source code a bit further, and it looks like there's a boolean value that controls whether gc_skill_rank considers buffs or not.  In nwn2, it seems to be hardcoded to always consider buffs.  That said, "buffs" should include everything: skill buffs, equipment bonuses/penalties, feats, ability scores, etc.  I'll write a test module when I get a chance to be sure